# Python pandas 5 GB

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am new to Python and I have problem with reading all data with pandas. File format is csv. Dimensions :740 000 x 600

I know there were a lot of similar questions but I still don't know how to do that. I tried read all data but my computer had frozen I don't know if this is a memory error or my computer have other problem with that. 
I want to have this data in pandas data frame format and in one piece. I read about making chunks but for further analysis I need all data in one variable.

Is it possible to read it in efficiency way?

I should add that I have 8 GB RAM.

Comment: Iguess you need to rethink your requirements. There is usually a way to restrict the data analysis to a subset of the complete data. Also the data format may be relevant. But all of that depends on what you are trying to accomplish and without you telling us, noone can help you.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : I would like to make PCA analysis on the whole data and xgboost analysis for feature selection

Comment: And why on the whole data and not a subset? E.g. what is the gain of PCA on a matrix with such large difference between columns and rows? I still think you either post a well defined problem or this question is simply too broad to be answered here.

Comment: Maybe This is my mistake but my task is to build knn algoritm and above data (which I mentioned) are my sample so as I think if this is my sample I should use all data to further analysis